# Running Rails tests against seeds.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing

I want to run tests against the current database instead of whatever is in fixtures/ . Looking at my SQL db, I have a Video (model) with ID 1. However, running

```
ruby functional\videos_controller_test.rb
```

gives me the error:

```
test_check_video_offsets(VideosControllerTest):
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Video with ID=1
app/controllers/videos_controller.rb:16:in `show'
```

This is all that is in the test right now:

```
test "check video offsets" do
  get :show, :id => "1"
  Rails::logger.debug @video
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it:

```
rake db:seed RAILS_ENV=test
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply set the database name for your test environment to the one of your active environment (development, production.) in your config/database.yml

```
base: &base
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  username: 
  password: 

development:
  <<: *base
  database: app_development

test: &test
  <<: *base
  database: app_development
```

Comment: That's one way, but is there a way to simple run db:seed on the test database?

Comment: Like you've mentioned below, yes. You can run anything against a specific environment by setting the environment variable RAILS_ENV.

Rails 3' "rails" command accepts environment for console and other commands as an argument too, though. Like "rails c test".